# Problems about function pointers in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

I am reading Linux kernel recently.
I find that in many cases they use the struct "typedef xxx f(xxx)", but I cannot understand how it works. (something like function pointer?)

Here is my test code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef int Myfunc(int);
typedef int (*point_to_myfunc)(int);
static Myfunc example;
static int example(int a){
    printf("example a=%d\n", a);
    return 1;
}
static void example2(Myfunc* f){
    printf("example2\n");
    f(2);
}
static void example3(int (*)(int));
static void example3(int (*point_to_Myfunc)(int)){
    printf("example3\n");
    point_to_Myfunc(3);
}
int main(){
    point_to_myfunc f=&example;
    example2(f);
    example3(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone provide a brief explanation for me? Thx~

Comment: Is `typedef int Myfunc(int);` even legal?

Comment: @Jueecy Why wouldn't it be? It has a very obvious meaning, so why would the Standard not allow it? if you want to know whether a typedef is legal, just remove "typedef" and see if it's a legal declaration. `int MyFunc(int);` ... yup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int Myfunc(int);
```

`Myfunc` is the name of a type; it is a function taking an `int` argument and returning an `int`.

```
typedef int (*point_to_myfunc)(int);
```

`point_to_myfunc` is a pointer to a function taking an `int` argument and returning an `int`.  You could also have: `typedef Myfunc *ptr_to_myfunc;` if you wished (another name for the same type).

```
static Myfunc example;
```

This says 'there exists a function called `example` of type `Myfunc`'.

```
static int example(int a)
{
    printf("example a=%d\n", a);
    return 1;
}
```

This is a possible implementation of `example`.  You can't use a typedef name to like `Myfunc` in the definition of a function of that type.

```
static void example2(Myfunc *f)
{
    printf("example2\n");
    f(2);
}
```

This is a function that takes a pointer to a `Myfunc`.  The line `f(2);` invokes the function pointed at with the argument 2 and ignores the returned value.

```
static void example3(int (*)(int));
```

This declares `example3` as a function taking a pointer to a function that takes an `int` argument and returns an `int` result.  It could have been written as `static void example3(point_to_myfunc);` or `static void example3(ptr_to_myfunc);` or `static void example3(Myfunc *);`.

```
static void example3(int (*point_to_Myfunc)(int))
{
    printf("example3\n");
    point_to_Myfunc(3);
}
```

This is an implementation of `example3`.

```
int main(void)
{
    point_to_myfunc f = &example;
    example2(f);
    example3(f);
    return 0;
}
```

This program has a variable `f` that's a pointer to a function.  Interestingly, you could have:

```
    point_to_myfunc f2 = example;
    point_to_myfunc f3 = *example;
```

Etc.  And they all mean the same thing.

You could also invoke them using:

```
    (*f2)(101);
    (**f3)(103);
```

The standard notation for the initialization would use neither the `&` nor the `*`.  If you're an old school C programmer, you may well invoke the function pointer using the `(*f2)(101)` notation; before the C89 standard, that was the only way to invoke function pointers.  Modern style tends to be `f2(101);` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear explanation. This usage is really powerful.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef int Myfunc(int);
```

This means that Myfunc is the type of a function which takes an int parameter and returns an int.

This line:

```
static Myfunc example;
```

is the same as saying

```
static int example(int);
```

which forward-declares the example function.

One use for this would be to make it clearer that a particular set of functions are used for a particular purpose.

```
typedef char CharacterConverter(char);

extern CharacterConverter make_upper_case;
extern CharacterConverter make_lower_case;

extern void process_string(char *s,CharacterConverter *f);
    // easier to see that make_upper_case and make_lower_case are valid arguments.
```

Comment: what would be the practical use of such typedef?

Comment: @Koushik: I've added one possible use.

Comment: +1. ah nice. there is a typo. its characterConverte(r) not (d).

Answer (score 1):

Vaughn Cato is correct,
In addition,

```
typedef int (*point_to_myfunc)(int);
```

defines a function pointer, it means point_to_myfunc is a type,we can use it like this:

```
point_to_myfunc f=&example;
```

now f is just like example(), we could f() to call method example

Answer (score 0):

typedef is useful when define a type.

For example:
`char *a, b;` defined a pointer "a", and a char b.
`char *a, *b` defined two char pointers.
If use typedef, it will be clear:

```
typedef char* PCHAR;
PCHAR a,b;
```

Now, both a and b is a char pointer.

```
typedef int Myfunc(int);
typedef int (*point_to_myfunc)(int);
```

the two lines defined a pair, a function format and a type of pointer which can point to the function, so it will be clear and more obvious when using them.

Comment: The OP didn't ask what `typedef` is or for an example of what it's good for.

Comment: You're right, My mistake.